# How can I use ImageDisk (.IMD) images with VirtualBox, WinImage, etc.?

Tags: floppy-disk, disk-image

I've got ImageDisk installed on my old 486, and I've been ripping some disks for archival purposes (some 3.5", some 5.25"). It spits out .IMD files, which contain some amount of header and metadata, and some basic compression. Is there a simple utility for converting these to a format that could be used with VirtualBox or other virtualization software, dd, or WinImage, in cases where the disk in question is FAT? I see many references to BIN2IMD, which converts raw images to ImageDisk format, but I'm not finding anything for doing the reverse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keir Fraser’s [Disk Utilities](https://github.com/keirf/Disk-Utilities) include an analysis and conversion program, `disk-analyse`, which can convert to and from ImageDisk files (among others). To convert an ImageDisk file to a plain MFM disk image suitable for use with virtualisation software, run

```
disk-analyse image.imd image.img
```

It might take a little while, and the program is silent at first which can be surprising.

Comment: Got it up and running on my Raspberry Pi. Just do `make; sudo make install; sudo ldconfig` in the libdisk directory, then `make; sudo make install` in disk-analyse. Takes a minute or two to convert a 1.2 MB image on my Pi, but works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

[libdsk](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/LibDsk) can convert IMD to a raw disc image.

```
dskconv -otype raw file.imd file.img
```

or in versions prior to 1.5.5:

```
dsktrans -otype raw file.imd file.img
```

Comment: Oh nice, it's got Windows binaries too. I'll have to give this one a try.

Answer (score 2):

In case users need a third option:

[dumpfloppy](https://offog.org/code/dumpfloppy/), by Adam Sampson:

> This is a suite of tools for reading floppy disks in arbitrary formats supported by the PC floppy controller, and for working with the resulting image files. For image files, it uses the IMD format defined by Dave Dunfield's ImageDisk. You can capture an image with dumpfloppy and then write it back with ImageDisk, or use the dumpfloppy tools to examine or extract an ImageDisk file.

Build instructions on Linux might typically be:

```
autoreconf ; ./configure ; make
```