# How to use BASIC-86 from Microsoft with SCP 8086 simulator

Tags: disk-image, simh, 86-dos, basic-86

After the exciting news that a very early version of 86-DOS (0.11) from Seattle Computer Products [was found](https://archive.org/details/86-dos-version-0.1-c-serial-11-original-disk) I played a bit with the [simh / Altair Z80 simulator](https://github.com/simh/simh) to run the 86-DOS image and was successful.

Later on I wanted to try v5.21 of Basic-86 [available](https://winworldpc.com/download/7d39c2a3-37c5-9273-11c3-a5c28f135254) from WinWorld, but I failed due missing instructions how to use it. When I include the disk image in the 86dos start script like this:

```
; $Id: 86dos 1968 2008-06-26 05:55:25Z hharte $
;
; SIMH/AltairZ80 Configuration File for SCP 86-DOS v1.0
; Copyright (c) 2008 Howard M. Harte
; www.86dos.org
;
; Press <return> to get into the Monitor, and then type
; 'B' to boot 86-DOS.
;
set cpu 8086

; load SCP Monitor
load 86mon.bin 0
load 86mon.bin ff800

; Set serial port for SCP
set sio port=f6/0/0/0/0/F/0/T
set sio port=f7/0/2/0/1/F/0/F
set sio ansi

; Set up Cromemco 4FDC disk controller, with RDOS ROM disabled.
set cromfdc norom
set cromfdc en
set wd179x en
d cromfdc fdctype 4
att cromfdc0 86dos10.imd
att cromfdc1 basic86.imd

; Start monitor, press enter to get '>' prompt.
echo
echo Press <return> to get monitor prompt, then type 'B' to boot
echo
go ffff0
```

I got this after executing `dir B:`

```
Altair 8800 (Z80) simulator V4.0-0 Current        git commit id: 4dfb3508
2047 bytes [8 pages] loaded at 0.
2047 bytes [8 pages] loaded at ff800.
Disk write-protected because the image contains compressed sectors. Use IMDU to uncompress.

Press <return> to get monitor prompt, then type 'B' to boot



SCP 8086 Monitor 1.5
>B

86-DOS version 1.00
Copyright 1980,81 Seattle Computer Products, Inc.
Enter today's date (m-d-y): 2-2-82

COMMAND v. 1.00

A:dir B:
h
    J<   212432011  14-10-82
=;Zs
      |;   218892250  07-08-70
h,^^Vh  O=Z   393195986  15-08-28
cx
  u
   Q[r  i   298705197  06-02-38
ixuhe


       h<   185031101  14-05-38
~<,u'kn:  o
              301749386  08-01-49
thw}u
       Rt   212481927  04-11-95
g       ;Z  um
                 375519962  07-08-:0
i&}iXu:
         R   278219546  04-07-89
ah}t  i   404443486  08-30-28
_Yivh  /
           213180499  05-14-93
[t|u  C<   303070646  00-30-97
~
 @tvhf{  <"u   264000488  00-05-80
hK{uh  ui   409318100  07-09-78
=S<,tp<  ;u   130421131  15-08-69

 J~h  u   112957950  09-18-80
 /
  @t)  us   121881881  06-00-38
tus~  H:E   240852791  01-10-80
hD


  0   0
          384358377  11-20-94
4
 h <  t
          350495184  08-14-37
hkzhS
     XP  <Tt   386088475  08-00-21
0
 @ 2u   3   381320729  14-26-25
,TSt"9*
         7   384356073  00-10-76
/k v  PB   427903744  11-25-81
h0 h:~M  uy[   426806302  07-24-49
Chd<#u  i?   335235610  10-18-21
iQR5  h!   318989427  11-18-35
t
C

   @u    57982986  00-10-60
i:rY;Qh  *D
              167396850  00-00-10
9OQ<"0  "6    92250816  09-12-38
h+ykh@  ;Sh   356531888  01-31-96
hT⸮Ysi  rQ   392599202  10-18-17
lyh
   K  <[t   365178098  11-21-81
i@<(tk  <[t   349056007  15-08-05
ir^^V
       <    57985278  00-00-60
iShmu  hZ   264320380  09-12-38
hkx
   @[t  ix~   448338823  05-02-25
hd,h⸮  ^^   124505600  11-20-81
"rhAt  iT   168057504  01-28-97
@
 pt6:5  ,Kh   182073223  08-01-77
^^VRim  zhb   365920843  10-06-96
t<,tiP  ~^    57989767  02-26-82
iwR[iI}  h_z   325616451  08-03-96
        Whx<  u]   392425042  09-08-17
Zh.2@"  O          264068353  00-04-10
rq,r
    Pu
         29543424  13-27-41
E.
  7:FsU  Q9    68919397  07-30-10
,uivp  6J   259047429  08-00-:7

J
 hQ  9o   289741872  01-20-10
P2F:F
     ps  i   342654469  15-08-84
kIRh,ZS  9`9604691  11-04-73
tix
   J  S9   278691388  09-26-78
<uis  9
       p   219644518  06-05-10
ui7ose  ;%   405114373  10-26-49
[+h96[    H[    46190596  04-17-82
C
 XG*C
       x.
            290998875  01-28-82
kQhh+YZ  ;90998875  04-09-95
keSZhz  4[h   343466243  15-09-95
h3riB  < s    58061628  01-28-:1
i<"ui
       <   400472296  09-28-87
-Sh([C  <Vu   323977772  06-03-10
he(<#u
        h=   377289690  08-20-00
ifvh#6[  C<R   227815599  14-29-38
uiQ<u  i   352821629  08-20-00

A:
```

So it looks not like a "normal" disk content. When I just try to use `att cromfdc0 basic86.imd` the simulator freezes after 'B'.
So does anyone know how to properly use that? (was also not able to find a User Manual for Basic-86 from Microsoft)

**EDIT:**
maybe it's needed to extract the imd (Image Disk) file because of that hint in the Readme of the zip file:

> This disk image contains two early releases of Microsoft BASIC-86, as
> provided by Microsoft for the Seattle Computer Products S-100
> machines.

I tried with [several tools](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/how-can-i-use-imagedisk-imd-images-with-virtualbox-winimage-etc) to convert the imd to img but was never be able to extract the content. Can anyone help here?!

Comment: Iteresting issue, but questions about configuration and operation of emulators are off topic on RC.SE, unless the observed behaviour is one of a real system. Image file corruption / emulator configuration doesn't look like being one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to solve it: the provided disk was in a wrong format and you have to copy it to a blank SCP formatted disk: (you need hexedit, cpm and cpmtools)

- Create a blank [IBM 3740](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3740) disk: `dd if=/dev/zero of=data.img count=256256 bs=1`
  (77 tracks with 26 sectors storing 128 bytes per sector => 256256 Bytes)
- Set all Bytes to `E5` (needed to treat as empty): e.g. `hexedit data.img` in Linux
- Prepare another new empty IBM 3740 disk called basic86.img and copy the `BASIC.COM` file from the BASIC-86 zip file over: `cpmcp -f ibm-3740 basic86.img ~/MS_BASIC-86_5.21/files/BASIC.COM 0:BASIC.COM`
- adapt the simh / Altair Z80 start script to have the BASIC-86 image and the empty disk: `att cromfdc0 86dos10.imd att cromfdc1 basic86.img att cromfdc2 data.img`
- boot the system and format data.img in drive C: `CLEAR C:`
- copy BASIC.COM from basic86.img to C: `RDCPM B:BASIC.COM C:BASIC.COM`
- switch to C: and execute BASIC

Comment: So as expected,a pure emulator issue, not related with the realsystem.

Comment: @Raffzahn I wouldn't say so because the provided disk image of BASIC-86 is in the wrong format.

Comment: Should be something similar to `dd if=/dev/zero count=256256 bs=1 | tr '\0' '\xe5' | dd of=data.img` (havent tested the xe5)

Answer (score -1):

While the problem in the original post had been solved, keeping the (generic) answer here for information.

Here is a list of instructions leading to a working state of the OS:

(1) Download 86-DOS disk image.

```
wget 'https://archive.org/download/86-dos-version-0.1-c-serial-11-original-disk/86-DOS%20Version%200.1-C%20-%20Serial%20%2311%20%28ORIGINAL%20DISK%29.imd'
 -O 86dos.imd
```

(2) Download 8086 monitor.

```
wget https://bitsavers.org/bits/SeattleComputerProducts/86-DOS/scp86mon.zip
unzip scp86mon.zip
```

(3) Build SIMH simulator.

```
git clone https://github.com/simh/simh.git
make -C simh altairz80
```

(4) Start 86-DOS.

```
simh/BIN/altairz80 scp86mon.txt
```

You should see:

```
$ simh/BIN/altairz80 scp86mon.txt

Altair 8800 (Z80) simulator V4.0-0 Current        git commit id: ee34e295
2047 bytes [8 pages] loaded at 0.
2047 bytes [8 pages] loaded at ff800.
Disk write-protected because the image contains compressed sectors. Use IMDU to uncompress.
_
```

Hit enter a few times and the SCP monitor prompt will come up, then hit uppercase "B" to boot.

```
SCP 8086 Monitor 1.5
>B

86-DOS version 0.11
Copyright 1980 Seattle Computer Products, Inc.

A:_
```

Type dir to see the disk contents.

```
A:dir
COMMAND  COM
RDCPM    COM
HEX2BIN  COM
ASM      COM
TRANS    COM
SYS      COM
EDLIN    COM
CHESS    COM
CHESS    DOC
```

Type chess to start a game.

```
A:chess

Choose your color (W/B): B
Ply depth (1-6): 2
e2 e4
_
```

Source: https://vak.dreamwidth.org/1156364.html

Comment: Have you read my task? I was able to do this but struggling with the BASIC-86 software from MS (download link on WinWorld).

Comment: @leon22 Have you bothered to check if 86dos10.imd and basic86.imd are of the same size and, if so, format (e. g. using the UNIX "file" tool)?  Have you tried typing "B:" first, then "dir"? Have you, instead, tried typing ctrl-E, then "att cromfdc0 basic86.imd" (changing disks in drive A:), then "dir"?